# New project in TFS 2015 does not have XAML build definition

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

We are trying to upgrade to TFS2015 and have done a test configuration for TFS 2015. 
I have noticed that if we create a new project in TFS2015 the project is all empty, it does not even have the BuildProcessTemplates folder.

Can anyone guide me on how to get the Default build definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that there is no BuildProcess Template folder created when you create a team project in TFS 2015.

If you have configure XAML build, you can download the build process template by creating a XAML build definition:

[image]

By the way, you can also check the new build system in TFS 2015, which is based on windows services, and doesn't need build process template. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/feature-overview

Comment: Thanks for the info. But after downloading the XAML template found that it is empty. How to customize it now? If you can point me to any link.

Comment: Assuming you were using TFS 2012 or prior before. Since TFS 2013, the build process template become simple, and the overall structure is easier to understand. You can Expand All to check the overall structure. You still can add activities to customize it. You may check this blog to get more knowledge of the the new build process template: http://www.alexandervanwynsberghe.be/whats-new-in-tfs-2013-build/